# Using MSBuild, can I sign an application where the password is specified in a file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

When I sign an application, I typically run a command line instruction like this:

```
msbuild /p:project=whatever;platform=all;configuration=sign;KeyFile=key.pfx;Password=pass;RunCodeAnalysis=false;StyleCopEnabled=false
```

Instead of specifying the password on the command line, is there an MSBuild property that lets me specify a file that contains the password? If not, is there any recommended procedure for signing, where the password is specified indirectly?

Comment: Is adding another buildfile also an option?

Comment: Response file maybe? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx

Comment: @leppie: I realize I could use a resp file. But notice that I asked if there's a MSBuild property to specify a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use BAT/CMD files instead of directly calling MSBuild:

You can insert content of the file into line that calls MSBuild using `set /p`

```
set /p MyPassword = <  path\to\file\Password.txt
msbuild ...;Password=%MyPassword%;
```

Comment: This seems like the best workaround; there doesn't seem to be a MSBuild property to specify a signing password that's in a file.