# Adding a strong name key (.pfx) file to a project programmatically

Tags: c#, code-signing, makecert, strong-named-key

I am able to create a self signed certificate and generate a .pfx file from code [using makecert and pvk2pfx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx). I can edit the project file programmatically (using regex, although an xmlreader implementation might also work and perhaps be safer) to edit the project file. However, after I add the .pfx file and set signing to true, the project no longer builds because I need to open VS to enter the password for the private key.

I would like to know if it is possible to add a .pfx file to a project programmatically after creating the .pfx file, **without** needing to open VS to enter the password.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835370/using-msbuild-can-i-sign-an-application-where-the-password-is-specified-in-a-fi

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `/f` (file) and `/p` (password) switches in a post-build event to sign the file.